# How can we construct Markov partitions for Smale Horseshoe and Solenoid?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

I was reading the book *[Ergodic Theory, Hyperbolic Dynamics and Dimension Theory](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-28090-0)* by Luis Barreira. In [Chapter 7](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-28090-0_7), it is asked to construct Markov partitions for the Smale Horseshoe and the solenoid. In general, there are Markov partitions with arbitrary small diameter for any locally maximal hyperbolic sets. I was wondering how we can explicitly construct those partitions. Where can I find some reference about this topic?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The construction for the Arnolds-CAT map (the automorphism of the 2-torus given by the matrix $\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}$) uses the two eigenspaces of this matrix. If you project those lines to the torus you get three rectangles which give you a Markov partition for this map. (There is also a 2-element Markov partition in this example, but it is a bit harder to construct.)

Comment: A reference would be the Handbook of dynamical systems by Hasselblatt and Katok, Volume 1, starting on page 324. The CAT map example is on pages 327-328. Another good source is the original paper by Adler and Weiss from 1967 and R. Bowen's paper on Axiom A from 1970. (By the way, constructing Markov partitions for higher dimensional tori etc. is much more complicated, as the borders of their atoms are fractal and not differentiable, hence the nice rectangles only happen to exist in 2 dimensions.)